# Android / фоновая служба

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!
Как при программировании Android приложения сделать так, чтобы при наступлении какого-то времени что-нибудь происходило (например звонил будильник)? Как я себе представляю - при нажатии какой-то кнопки запускаем фоновую службу (демон), которая "слушает" системное время. Правильно ли это? Нужен ли мне приемник широковещательных сообщений? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Для задания повторяющихся действий, используйте AlarmManager

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE , 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND , 0);
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, code, i, 0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

(Код требует доводки.)

Для задания действия с какой-то задержкой используйте Handler:

```
private custome new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // TODO: Требуемое действие
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: спасибо! с будильником ясно. а в случае, если нужно, к примеру, менять обои в определенное время?

Comment: или выключать wifi?